# Monotouch custom controls, how?

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, ipad, xamarin.ios

I want to create a custom ui control for my monotouch application.
My control consists in a view with 2 labels and 1 image. I need to re-use it more times.

Can i develop a custom uiview in monotouch? is possible to use custom controls in Interface Builder?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog)